# Altering Url with onclick tag in btn

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I used the following in one view in order to navigate to a specific tab on an Index view...

```
  button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="location.href='Index/#rooms'"><i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Back to Room List</button>
```

The Url reads like.....ReferralTarget/Index/#rooms

rooms being one of the tabs on the Index view..

When I use the same code in another view, I get an error 400 - Bad request and the Url reads like... /ReferralTarget/EditRoom/Index/#rooms

```
   @model.Project.Web.Models.ReferralTargetRoomModel
  @{
  ViewBag.Title = "EditRoom";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
 <div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span12">
 <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->   
 <div class="portlet box blue">
 <div class="portlet-title">
 <div class="caption"><i class="icon-hospital"></i>Edit Room Details</div>      
</div>
<div class="portlet-body form">
<!-- BEGIN FORM-->

               @using (Html.BeginForm("EditRoom", "ReferralTarget", FormMethod.Post,     new { @class="form-horizontal" }))
              {
              @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
              @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferralTargetId)
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.County)</label>
    <div class="controls">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.County.ID, new SelectList(Model.Counties, "ID", "Name"), new {@id="counties" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County)
    </div>                                  
            <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fax)</label>
    <div class="controls">   
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fax)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fax)
    </div>
    </div>
            <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)</label>
    <div class="controls">   
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    </div>
            <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website)</label>
    <div class="controls">   
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Website)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Website)
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Users)</label>
    <div class="controls">   
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsers,  new MultiSelectList(Model.Users,"ID","Name",Model.SelectedUsers)
           , new { @id = "users"  , @multiple = true})
</div>
</div>                                      
<div class="form-actions">
   <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn green">
  <button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="location.href='Index/#rooms'"><i    class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Back to Room List</button>
    </div>
           }                                
    <!-- END FORM-->  
    </div>
</div>
     <!-- END SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
                </div>
   @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.multi-select.js")
    }
   @section Styles {
    <link href="~/assets/css/multi-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  }
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#users').multiSelect({
     selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Availible Users</div>",
     selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selected Users</div>",
   });
   });
   $(function () {
    $("#counties").change(function () {
    var filterVal = $("#counties").val();
   getHospitalsByCounty(filterVal);
   })
  });
    function getHospitalsByCounty(value) {
    $.ajax({
     url: 'GetHospitalsInCounty?id=' + value,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (response) {
     var data = response;
     var items = []
    $('#hospitals').empty();
   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
  $('#hospitals').append($('<option></option>').val(value.ID).html(value.Name));
   });
 }
});
 };
 });
 </script>
```

Is there a way of altering the url to remove text, in this case "Edit room"..??

If it's related back to the controller, the only difference in the two views is the EditView Get ActionResult uses a (string id), where the AddView does not....

Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you want? This question is confusing?

Comment: I have three views - Index - Addroom - EditRoom.      Index has tabs, one of these tabs is named Rooms - while in the Addroom View I click on the Back to Rooms Btn, to return to the Index view with the rooms tab displayed (this works)....When I click the same btn in the EditRoom view I get an error 400-bad request and the Url display's EditRoom/Index/#rooms when it should read Index/#rooms.....is there a way to remove the EditRoom in the onclick ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i think you've unintentionally added a non existing action method.

Is `EditRoom` the action you want or is `Index` the action you want.

I'm guessing the Controller is `ReferralTarget`.

So it should be `ReferralTarget/EditRoom/#rooms`

**UPDATED**

You could change this line.

```
 onclick="location.href='Index/#rooms'"
```

To

```
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","ReferralTarget")/#rooms'"
```

Comment: No I want to return to the Index ActionResult....Controller is ReferralTarget.......it should read ReferralTarget/Index/#rooms

Comment: @mkell Can you show the view code for the editroom? this would help to know what needs to be changed.

Comment: Any particular part , it too long for a comment in this form...first sect..@model PrejectName.Web.Models.ReferralTargetRoomModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "EditRoom";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ReferralTargetRoomModel</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferralTargetId)   then just looking for info for text boxes.....then a save input type sumit and the btn code as before...any clearer?

Comment: @mkell I was hoping you'd update your question to provide more info. simply add the entire view to you question so we can see how to help.

Comment: Apologies, updated...

Comment: @mkell i've updated my answer .. you can try that now.

Comment: Thank you , sir, that was really starting to bug me, I am not a fan of Mondays...Much appreciated..